# String doesn't want to be shown in TextView

Tags: android

I've got such a String Variable:

```
mashTimeDurationCombined = beer.getMashTemperature() + "℃ / " + beer.getMashduration() + "min";
System.out.println(mashTimeDurationCombined);
```

I can print that in console and message shows what I expect, when I want that message to be set on TextView, field remains empty.

```
mashTempDuration = findViewById(R.id.mashTempDurationViewID);
mashTempDuration.setText(mashTimeDurationCombined);
```

Here is xml code of view:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mashTempDurationViewID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/mashTempAndDuration"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/boilVolume" />
```

This is not first view that I'm inflating with text but this time I really don't know what is wrong about it...

Comment: try adding text via android:text="xx" and see if its visible, maybe some issue with layout.

Comment: is it visible now ?? you can change the text colors attrubute and test...i doubt you mixed with the color with layout background!!

Comment: the code seems fine.  it must be something else.  perhaps color, perhaps the text view is getting pushed off the screen based on your constraints,

Comment: problem was, that I accidentally initialized my view twice and IDE doesn't show any error with that so I've had to review all my views to find that out. Thank you for response